# What Year Is the Ford Anglia?

Tags: harry-potter

**What year is the *Harry Potter* Ford Anglia?**

I Googled using "Harry Potter Ford Anglia" and "Harry Potter Ford Anglia Year" and while I was able to get the model number (Ford Anglia 105E), I wasn't able to find a consensus on what year the *Harry Potter* Anglia was made. I did learn that the particular model of Ford Anglias in *Harry Potter* were produced between 1959 and 1967 and have distinctive tailfins and a inwardly curving frame on the rear window.

★ I usually ask for only canon sources, but I have never seen a reference to the Anglia's year in any of the *Harry Potter* books or J.K. Rowling interviews, or on Pottermore. Of course if you can find the answer in canon, that's great! Per usual, I am ***not*** looking for an answer from the HP Wikia or the Wikipedia.

Comment: It seems that the registration number of the Anglia is either "7990 TD" (going by the movies) or "COS 207" (going by Pottermore). According to http://www.speedyreg.co.uk/history-of-number-plates, either of these numbers would be issuable before 1963, but not after.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There were several different cars used in the making of the film version. Different internet sources describe different vehicles. According to [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/50415738@N04/5962413849/), one of the props was a 1966 Ford Anglia Deluxe 105E.

> Nigel Grint, father of Rupert Grint owns *one of* the original cars
>   used in the making of the movie "Harry Potter and the Chamber of
>   Secrets". It is now on display at the National Motor Museum in
>   Beaulieu, Hampshire, England.

[image: Pic] (Please note: This is not Mr. Grint's vehicle. You can view *his* car on the [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/50415738@N04/5962413849/) link)

That being said, you can find additional info regarding another *original* 1960 Potter car, including images at [Internet Movie Cars Data Base](http://www.imcdb.org/vehicle_2123-Ford-Anglia-105E-1960.html)

Comment: Amusingly, your Internet Movie Cars Database link says it is a 1960 Ford Anglia [105E].

Comment: @JackBNimble editted to CMA.

Answer (score 7):

The car used in the movie is a turquoise 1962 Ford Anglia. This BBC article states how it went missing from the studios located in Cornwall.

[Harry Potter's 'flying' car taken](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/england/cornwall/4384244.stm)

> The turquoise 1962 Ford Anglia was being stored at the St Agnes studios, which went into receivership last year.

[image]

Comment: It seems apparent that one can't speak of "the" car used in the movie, because there were almost certainly several cars used in the movie.

Answer (score 4):

There were 9 cars used by the studios. All in different stages of decay and damage to consist with the story. There were running versions, and cut up versions. Even the one with ejecting seats. There is no one car, but the Anglia 105E owner's club names it as a 1962 Ford Anglia 105E Saloon Deluxe due to its registration. John Colyer its President, worked with the FX company that sourced the vehicles to the studios. Consequently the studios have bout 7 more cars as shells for Harry Potter themed parks, studio tour and the Harry Potter prop exposition tour.

And the car in the national museum was not a studio car. It is actually a Ford Anglia Super 123E. It may or may not be owned by the Grint family, but no Anglia Super was ever used in the movie, other than for a shell that was fitted with a 105E grille. See grille and you can tell they are not the same. The front quarter light in the grille next to the stalker light does not exist in a true 105E.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Harry Potter Wiki the descriptions place the Ford Anglia as a 1963 or earlier (so 1960-1963) http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Ford_Anglia

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, @slytherincess has specifically asked for answers that aren't sourced solely by HP Wikia or Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

My fathers Wolseley was 7412 TD and was registered in 1961. TD was a Lancashire suffix and I would imagine that 7990 TD would have been registered at the same time - probably even the same month.

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange! One thing to keep in mind, though, is that there were multiples cars used in the movie, as detailed in the other answers. Prop license plates are probably easy to make, or they could just swap the plates. So this is likely the year of only *one* of the cars used.